# How to Compare Two Meta Fields

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

Consider two meta fields `balance` and `monthly_price`. How you would get all posts that has `balance < monthly_price`

Thinking of creating meta query but our both fields are arbitrary or do not have specific value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A rought method would be to set value of `balance` to `'mt1.meta_value'` and then use a `'posts_request'` filter to remove the escaping quotes:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', // maybe not
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'balance',
      'compare' => '>=',
      'value' => 'mt1.meta_value', // this will be treated as a string
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
    // this is to force adding the needed JOIN clause
    array(
      'key' => 'monthly_price', 
      'compare' => 'EXISTS' 
    ),
    'relation' => 'AND'
  )
);

$closure = function( $sql ) {
  // remove single quotes around 'mt1.meta_value'
  return str_replace( "'mt1.meta_value'", "mt1.meta_value", $sql );
};

add_filter( 'posts_request', $closure );

$query = new \WP_Query( $args ); // this is your query :)

remove_filter( 'posts_request', spl_object_hash( $closure ) );
```

I should add that I used `'mt1.meta_value'` because WordPress when multiple meta queries are in the args use table aliases like `"mt{$n}"` where `$n` is incremented for each additional query.

Comment: Interesting usage of `spl_object_hash` to remove filters with anonymous function callbacks +1

Comment: Thanks @birgire, as said in loopchat, that's the main reason why I posted this answer :)

Comment: So, if we have say 3 array of meta query and I put the `balance` query on the third one I should use `mt3.meta_value` instead?

Comment: @Sisir `mt2.meta_value`. The first meta is not aliased, is called with real name `wp_postmeta` if "wp" is table prefix. the second is `mt1` (as in the example), third is `mt2` and so on. However I have to say that with more than 2 meta ket this method is not really affordable...