# What's wrong with this WP query?

Tags: wp-query, mysql

With kind help of Sally CJ who answered my [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/392502/order-by-nested-named-meta-queries-with-exists-and-not-exists), I was able to create a WP Query, but it still gives me unexpected results. When I write the query in raw MySQL, it works fine, but with the query WordPress creates, it doesn't.

Here are my WP query arguments:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'tdlrm_store_item',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'store-category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => 514,
                'include_children' => false
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    'has_tdlrm_mp' => array(
                        'key'  => 'tdlrm_mp',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                    ),
                    'no_tdlrm_mp'  => array(
                        'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    'has_1C_quantity_total' => array(
                        'key'  => '1C_quantity_total',
                        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
                        ),
                    'no_1C_quantity_total'  => array(
                        'key'     => '1C_quantity_total',
                        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                        ),
                    )
       ),
       'orderby' => 'none',
       'tdlrm_commands' => array('tdlrm_orderby' => true)
);
```

Here's my `posts_orderby` filter:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, $query ){
    
    if (!isset($query->query_vars['tdlrm_commands']['tdlrm_orderby'])
    ||  $query->query_vars['tdlrm_commands']['tdlrm_orderby'] !== true) return $orderby;

    global $wpdb;

    return "
    CASE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN 1
        WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN 2
        ELSE 3 
    END ASC,
    CASE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0
    END ASC,
    CASE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key
        WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0
    END DESC,
    {$wpdb->posts}.post_date DESC
    ";
}, 10, 2 );
```

Here's the MYSQL query I wrote trying to figure out what's going on. It orders posts in such a way that the ones that have `tdlrm_mp` meta go first, ordered by meta value, lowest to highest, then the others, ordered by the `1C_quantity_total` meta value, highest to lowest, then the ones that have no `1C_quantity_total` meta, ordered by post date.

```
SELECT
    * FROM wp_postmeta 
    
    LEFT JOIN wp_posts on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    
    WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'tdlrm_store_item'
    AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 514

    ORDER BY 
    CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN 1
        WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN 2
        ELSE 3 
    END ASC,
    CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0
    END ASC,
    CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
        WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0
    END DESC,
    wp_posts.post_date DESC

    LIMIT 0,12
```

It works as expected. However, what I get with $query->request is this, and it doesn't work:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts

LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'tdlrm_mp' )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id AND mt3.meta_key = '1C_quantity_total' )

WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (514) )
AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'tdlrm_mp' OR mt1.post_id IS NULL ) AND ( mt2.meta_key = '1C_quantity_total' OR mt3.post_id IS NULL ) )
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'tdlrm_store_item'
AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))

GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 

ORDER BY
CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
    WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN 1
    WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN 2
    ELSE 3
END ASC,
CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
    WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0
END ASC,
CASE wp_postmeta.meta_key
    WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN wp_postmeta.meta_value+0
END DESC,
wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 12
```

The first posts are the ones that have the `tdlrm_mp` meta, and they get ordered just fine, but the rest get ordered by date, and that's it. What causes the difference between the MYSQL query I wrote and the WP MYSQL query, and how do I make it all work?

**Update.**

Turns out, WordPress joins the postmeta table several times, depending on the meta query arguments. This is how:

```
    //php
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation'     => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'  => 'tdlrm_mp',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            array(
                'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'key'  => '1C_quantity_total',
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    );

  //MySQL query by WordPress
  "...LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (
    wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (
    wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id 
    AND mt1.meta_key = 'tdlrm_mp'
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id) 
  WHERE..."
```

This means the `1C_quantity_total` meta key has to be referenced as `mt2.meta_key`, not `wp_postmeta.meta_key`. I rewrote the orderby filter like this, and it works:

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function ( $orderby, $query ){

    if (! isset( $query->query['tdlrm_commands'] ) ||
        ! $query->query['tdlrm_commands']['default_filter']
    ) return $orderby;

    global $wpdb;

    return "
    CASE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END ASC,
    CASE {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key
        WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0
    END ASC,
    CASE mt2.meta_key
        WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN mt2.meta_value+0
    END DESC
    ";
}, 10, 2 );
```

Now, I don't feel like hard-coding the table's alias, mt2. What if the alias changes in future versions of WordPress (e.g. mtB)? Also, I'm not sure `1C_quantity_total` will be in exactly the third joined postmeta table in any circumstances. Is there a way to do it better? Like, "find the joined table `1C_quantity_total` is actually in, then order by the value in that table".

**Update 2**

Thank you Sally CJ for helping me out, you're great!

While trying to solve this problem, I came across a number of questions that may be useful to whoever comes here:
[question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274941/set-alias-for-meta-query-arguments-in-get-posts), [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/359367/wordpress-creating-excessive-joins-on-meta-query-with-search), [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/164032/how-to-compare-two-meta-fields), [JOIN speed](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38530/most-efficient-way-to-get-posts-with-postmeta/), [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40322/query-multiple-meta-key-values/), [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173377/how-to-use-filter-hook-posts-join-for-querying-taxonomy-terms-in-posts-where/), [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/390191/compare-two-meta-fields-in-a-wp-query-where-meta-field-a-is-larger-than-meta-fi/).

Comment: PS: There's a typo in your question/code - the `'tdlrm_commands' =` should be `'tdlrm_commands' =>`. Also, it seems you forgot to close the `meta_query` array which then causes the `orderby` and `tdlrm_commands` be part of the `meta_query`..

Comment: Sally, the typos are just here, not on my site. The code actually works, it produces different queries as expected, when I set my 'tdlrm_orderby' to true or false. The orderby part you wrote appears in the query. What I'm trying to wrap my head around is why it works in the query I wrote manually, but doesn't work in the query WordPress produces.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my typos, though.

Comment: Have you actually tried running the SQL command in the `$query->request` via phpMyAdmin (but replace the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID` with `wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title`) - how's the outcome; did the sorting work correctly?

Comment: BTW, you asked about any previous queries. I've got wp_reset_query() right before my current query.

Yea, I did try running the SQL command and it did not work out, the ordering is different. I'm going to create a blank demo page now, where I'll retrieve data two ways, via WP Query and via $wpdb query, and see if there will be any difference. Maybe it's something in my page template that's messing things up

Comment: Yes, maybe. But with the raw SQL I mentioned, you could try removing the `, wp_posts.post_date DESC` and see if that might be the problem. But other than the typos that you've now already corrected, your `WP_Query` args and SQL command actually looked just fine to me.

Comment: Wait. Why did you have to call `wp_reset_query()`? You did not actually call `query_posts()`, did you? And if you were just trying to restore the global `$post` variable, then use `wp_reset_postdata()` and not `wp_reset_query()`.

Comment: I have not sorted it out yet, but I found out that WP uses LEFT JOIN to join `wp_postmeta` several times, so the `1C_quantity_total` meta is actually in the THIRD joined wp_postmeta table, its alias is mt2. Something like `CASE mt2.meta_key WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN mt2.meta_value+0 END DESC` would work, I guess... I'm currently trying to find a way to change the orderby filter without hardcoding the alias (what if it changes in the future).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Turns out, WordPress joins the postmeta table several times, depending
> on the meta query arguments.

Yes that's correct, and it's also the reason why I said (in my [other answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/392525)) that in an `orderby` *array*, you should use the key of an array in the `meta_query` which contains a direct item named/keyed `key` (where the value is a meta key) — and if you don't, then WordPress will not know which table join/alias should be used.

> This means the `1C_quantity_total` meta key has to be referenced as
> `mt2.meta_key`, not `wp_postmeta.meta_key`.

Yes, you're absolutely right!

( And sorry, my bad, I revised my other answer several times and yet, I actually still forgot to correct the table alias  )

> Now, I don't feel like hard-coding the table's alias, mt2. What if the
> alias changes in future versions of WordPress (e.g. mtB)? Also, I'm
> not sure `1C_quantity_total` will be in exactly the third joined
> postmeta table in any circumstances. Is there a way to do it better?

Yes, there is: use [`WP_Meta_Query::get_clauses()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/get_clauses/) to get the correct alias used for each meta query clause. And with a `WP_Query` instance, you can access the meta query class instance using the `$meta_query` property, i.e. `WP_Query::$meta_query`.

But *remember to give a unique **array key** to your meta query clauses like the `has_tdlrm_mp` and `has_1C_quantity_total`*:

```php
$args = array(
    ...
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'relation'     => 'OR',
            'has_tdlrm_mp' => array(
                'key'  => 'tdlrm_mp',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            'no_tdlrm_mp'  => array(
                'key'     => 'tdlrm_mp',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation'              => 'OR',
            'has_1C_quantity_total' => array(
                'key'  => '1C_quantity_total',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            'no_1C_quantity_total'  => array(
                'key'     => '1C_quantity_total',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
        )
   ),
   ...
);
```

So with that meta query, you can get the correct table alias like so:

```php
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$meta_clauses = $query->meta_query->get_clauses();

var_dump(
    $meta_clauses['has_tdlrm_mp']['alias'],
    $meta_clauses['has_1C_quantity_total']['alias'],
);
// Sample output: string(11) "wp_postmeta" string(3) "mt2"
```

And inside the `posts_orderby` filter/callback, you can use the same `$query->meta_query->get_clauses()` above, like so:

```php
$meta_clauses = $query->meta_query->get_clauses();

$has_tdlrm_mp          = $meta_clauses['has_tdlrm_mp']['alias'];
$has_1C_quantity_total = $meta_clauses['has_1C_quantity_total']['alias'];

return "
CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
    WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
END ASC,
CASE {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_key
    WHEN 'tdlrm_mp' THEN {$has_tdlrm_mp}.meta_value+0
END ASC,
CASE {$has_1C_quantity_total}.meta_key
    WHEN '1C_quantity_total' THEN {$has_1C_quantity_total}.meta_value+0
END DESC
";
```

Comment: Yes and sorry about my initial answer - I was just being confused (and seemed to have continued being so... confused).. Anyway, I hope the revised answer helps. :)

Comment: Yea, the question that keeps people confused is either a bad one or a great one )))

Comment: Phew... Sally, we did it! You're just great, thank you for your patience and your knowledge!